# Standing ovations for this question?

Tags: usage

This is from an article in today's *Zeit Online*:

> Als Rackete jüngst in Bremen beim 55. Kapitänstag auftrat, erhielt die
>   junge Frau mit den Dreadlocks nach ihrer 13-minütigen Rede von den
>   versammelten Kapitänen *Standing Ovations*.

Source: https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2019-09/radikalitaet-politischer-realismus-deutschland

All the results on the first 20 pages of a Google search on the English phrase "*Standing Ovations*" are from pages written in German. The reason why there are no English pages in the Google search is that English uses the singular. For example: *The crowd gave her a standing ovation.*

I understand why German uses English words and phrases when there is no exact equivalent, but why does German use English here when it already has "*stehende Ovationen*"? And why does it pluralize it?

Comment: Some discussion elsewhere about that: https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewWrongentry.php?idforum=7&idThread=436781&lp=ende . Also here: https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-stehende-ovation-stehbeifall-a-307500.html

Comment: Kind of similar example would be the English "Happy Ending" vs the German "Happy End"

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ. Thanks for the links. It's interesting that in German "_Standing Ovations_" can be performed while sitting. (If you summarize the contents of the articles in English, I'll accept your answer.)

Comment: @Shoe Well, I am not about writing an answer right now. Feel free to write your own answer summary, of what you understood from the links.

Comment: That's what we call *Denglish*. Used by people who want to be received as cosmopolites. Don't misunderestimate them.

Comment: Because we're ignorant? Seriously, anglicism is usually introduced by people who don't fully grasp both languages. This is how you get semi-accurate borrowings, pseudo-borrowings like "Handy", folk etymologies etc.

Comment: @Kilian Foth. Here's another pseudo-borrowing from today's ZON: _pullunder_, another word that doesn't exist in English. https://www.zeit.de/zeit-magazin/2019/38/pullunder-hans-dietrich-genscher-ludwig-stiegler-stil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ovation* originally is neither English nor German, but Latin. Furthermore, the term does not seem to have entered German via English.

> Ovation f. ‘Huldigung, Beifallssturm’, im 16. Jh. entlehnt aus lat. *ovātio* (Genitiv *ovātiōnis*), das im antiken Rom den ‘kleinen Triumph’ bezeichnet, bei dem der siegreiche Feldherr zu Pferde oder zu Fuß, nicht auf einem Wagen, Einzug hält; zu lat. *ovāre* ‘frohlocken, jubeln, siegreichen Einzug halten’. Dieser Bedeutung entsprechend, wird *Ovation* zunächst für feierliche Ehrungen von Fürsten oder bedeutenden Künstlern verwendet, danach (19. Jh.), wohl dem Bedeutungswandel von frz. *ovation* folgend, im Sinne von ‘begeisterter, stürmischer Beifall’ gebraucht. *(Pfeifer, nach [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ovation))*

Note that German does use the singular.

> Stark waren auch der Aargauer Schiedsrichter Urs Meier, der die dynamische Partie souverän leitete, sowie der Anhang Manchesters, der sein Team bis zum Abpfiff anfeuerte und danach beide Teams mit einer stehenden Ovation verabschiedete. *(St. Galler Tagblatt, 24.04.1997)*
>
> Mit einer 20-minütigen Ovation feiert das Galapublikum Michael Moore, den massigen David in seinem Kampf gegen einen Goliath namens George W. Bush. *(FOCUS, 24.05.2004)*
>
> Bei der Ehrenrunde zum Abschluß des Leichtathletik-Sportfestes im sauerländischen Arnsberg hing an Dieter Baumann wie immer eine große Kindertraube, und als er entlang der gut gefüllten Tribüne an der Zielgeraden vorbeikam, blieb er stehen und verneigte sich vor den Zuschauern, die ihm stehend eine Ovation spendierten. *(Süddeutsche Zeitung, 19.05.1998)*

In English, the plural is used to refer to multiple distinct events of clapping.

> There were more standing ovations than I've ever heard. (*Campbell, [Wigan Pier Revisited](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=Lk78h2E9A-0C&q=standing+ovations))*

However, in German, there are many cases where the plural is used when a singular is expected.

> Mit Ovationen hat das Publikum im Wiener Burgtheater die Uraufführung des Werkes «Sportstück» der österreichischen Autorin Elfriede Jelinek bedacht. Der minutenlange, von Bravo-Rufen begleitete Applaus galt sowohl den mehr als 100 Schauspielern wie auch der Autorin und dem wegen seiner bisherigen Arbeit umstrittenen deutschen Regisseur Einar Schleef. *(St. Galler Tagblatt, 26.01.1998)*
>
> An einen Moment erinnert sich Frank Deterding immer wieder gern. Simone Rethel, die Frau des bald 105-jährigen Johannes Heesters, spielte in Wolfsburg. Der greise Joopie begleitete sie, wurde aber erst kurz vor Vorstellungsbeginn zu seinem Platz geführt. Obwohl der Saal schon im Halbdunkel lag, erkannten die Zuschauer den ältesten aktiven Schauspieler. Sie bedachten ihn mit Ovationen, die bei Deterding ein Gänsehaut-Gefühl hinterließ. *(Braunschweiger Zeitung, 06.09.2008)*
>
> Wenn einer schon stehende Ovationen erhält, nur weil er die Bühne betritt, dann ist das nicht irgendwer. *(Hamburger Morgenpost, 15.07.2013)*

I think the verdict has to be that sometimes, plurals occur without a change in meaning. I recently encountered the following curious pair (note that singular and plural could easily be switched around).

> ein Wort des Dankes – Worte des Trostes *([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wort))*

Another example is

> Irritation(en) hervorrufen

where the plural seems more popular than the singular, without any obvious distinction in meaning.

In my opinion, the unexpected pluralisation of borrowed *standing ovations* in German is due to the "ornamental" plural of native (or nativised) *Ovationen*.

The fact that *standing ovation(s)* (again, the singular does occur) is used at all when *(stehende) Ovation(en)* is available is either a testament to the popularity of the English language in Germany or a sign of linguistic decline, depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is simply a tradition to use the English term ***standing ovations*** for standing ovations (i.e. people clapping their hands while being raised from their seats) also in German.

Whereas, if you try to translate it literally into something more German-ish, you get into trouble with style and syntax. The reason is that something like *stehende Ovationen* would be perceived as **Ovationen who are standing**, and that's nonsense, or at least bad style, as for the precision-prone German mind it is not the *Ovationen* who are on their feet but the people who offer those ovations.

I suppose the English mind (nothing being said about lack of precision on its side) is more inclined to hear something like "ovations while [people are] standing"; however, this detour is hardly possible for the German ear. There is no inclination in the German-speaking public to understand *stehende Ovationen* as "Ovationen [durch] stehende [Personen]", partly because as you see this would require much more syntactical transformations than in English.

If you insist on using a fully German-ized term, you have to take refuge to something like

> Steh-Ovationen <sup>1</sup>

(like Stehcafé, Steh-Empfang, Stehpult) but this is not a term really in use. I just made it up for you. It sounds odd, or purposefully humourous.

If you need an expression that is well-formed and accepted by the German speaking public you can say

> Als der Dirigent den Taktstock endgültig senkte, verharrte das Publikum für einige Sekunden in vollkommener Stille. Dann brach tosender Applaus aus, und die Gäste erhoben sich von ihren Sitzen.

(I admit that the English expression is shorter.)

Note: there are other English expressions that are in use in German everyday language like "Sorry" for *Tschuldigung*, "Fuck" for *Verflixt!* or "Sale" for *Ausverkauf* (well, as for the latter: people don't say "Sale" when talking to each other, but shop owners print it on their windows everywhere).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that commenter Userunknown finds this not precise enough and suggests to rather use *Aufsteh-Ovationen*.

Comment: Da Du unsere Präzision so hervorhebst: Es sollte aber, wie Du selbst dann bemerkst, Aufstehovation heißen, denn das charakteristische ist nicht, dass sie stehend dargebracht wird, sondern dass man für sie bzw. während dieser aufsteht. Bei einer bereits die ganze Zeit stehenden Menge wäre der Begriff verfehlt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I have with the German usage, apart from the fact that there is already a German equivalent, is the pluralization. There is only one _ovation_, defined in the OAL as _enthusiastic clapping by an audience as a sign of their approval_. I agree that _Rackete erhielt Standing Ovations_ avoids the gender problem: _Rackete erhielt ?einen/eine/ein? Standing Ovation_. But this is a problem with all borrowings, and as I say the whole problem is avoided by use of the German term.

Comment: @userunknown Der Gedanke ist berechtigt. Allerdings sagt auch der Anglophone ja nicht *raising ovations* oder *raised ovations*. - Ich werde trotzdem in Zukunft *Aufsteh-Ovationen* sagen. Man kann nie genau genug sein. Oder sollten wir noch deutscher werden und *Aufsteh-Preisung* sagen?

Comment: @Shoe  Well, yes. I would say: the constant use of "Standing Ovations" in plural in German - as opposed to the predominant (but not exclusive) use of *standing ovation* in singular in English - is simply an indicator of this term (Standing Ovations) being really well-integrated into German everyday communication. It may have been borrowed from the English speaking world quite some time ago in plural, or may have taken on the plural at one moment, in an independent development from what is typical use in English.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite common thing in German called "Pseudoanglizismus" - so a wrong English term being used in German. Popular example is "Handy" for mobile phone. I assume "Standing Ovations" is another example for this phenomenon.